# CSS body gradient

Tags: css, gradient

I am making a background in the `body` element but when I make a background it uses the window `height` (only the visible height) and if the user scrolls the page down the `background` repeats it self. If I use `no-repeat` the rest of the page is in solid color.

I have used `background-size: 100% 100%;` but still not working.

I only want a background that goes from #ccc to #000 and fills the entire page without repeating itself.....

Can anyone be so kind and help me? Thanks in advanced!

EDIT:
My code is:

```
body {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;

    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background: rgb(204,204,204);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(204,204,204,1) 0%, rgba(0,0,0,1) 100%);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,rgba(204,204,204,1)), color-stop(100%,rgba(0,0,0,1)));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(204,204,204,1) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,1) 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(204,204,204,1) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,1) 100%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(204,204,204,1) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,1) 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(top,  rgba(204,204,204,1) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,1) 100%);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#cccccc', endColorstr='#000000',GradientType=0 );
}
```

## LAST EDIT:

```
body {
    background: #000;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#ccc), to(#000)); /* for webkit browsers */
}
```

**note:** The best solution I found. When I scroll the window you can see the `background` color because the `background-image` does not repeat and as the `background-image` ends with the same `background` color everything is ok!

Comment: Show more code. Make sure that the element you're styling has the correct height (and width), by applying `min-height:100%;min-width:100%;`. If you're still not sure, have a look at the documentation of [background gradients](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/-moz-linear-gradient).

Comment: how about showing us your code ? or better - a jsfiddle link ?

Comment: Try `background-attachment: fixed`.

Comment: A gradient from `#ccc` to `#000`? `D:`

Comment: @antisanity: Hello! Yes I tried that but I don't like it fixed, I prefer it more "interactive"...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, you cannot stretch out background images, so what you are seeing is actually what you're supposed to see. Normally when sites use gradients as background images, they make it so the top of the gradient is flush with the top of the screen by setting `background-position: 0 0`, the gradient repeats itself horizontally by setting `background-repeat: no-repeat`, and then they set the `background-color` of the site to be the same color as the bottom of the gradient.

There are ways using CSS3 and filters in which you can create gradients for users, but there is a limited amount of browser-compatibility for these features. Here is a fiddle containing a gradient: http://jsfiddle.net/Wexcode/qhMx9/. See [this article](http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/cross-browser-css-gradient) for more information about those features.

Comment: You might want to also add `background-attachment: fixed` as @antisanity's comment suggests.

Comment: Thanks! I solved it like this (example for webkit only):body {
 background: #000;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#ccc), to(#000)); /* for webkit browsers */ }

Comment: I am new in the stackoverflow and I need 15 points to vote it but I want you to know that you helped me finding the way! I said "thank you" feedback!

Comment: Yes I know how now... Thanks! :)